# d3.js Gantt chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
var tasks;   
d3.json("http://localhost:8080/result", function(error, data) {   
tasks = data   
data.forEach(function(d) {   
d.startDate = new Date(d.maxTime["$date"]);   
d.endDate = new Date(d.minTime["$date"]);   
});   

var taskNames = ["Bob", "Sam"];   

var gantt = d3.gantt().taskTypes(taskNames);   
gantt(data);   
});
```

I am using help from [here](http://bl.ocks.org/dk8996/5449641) 
This is what the my array of `json` objects returned from http://localhost:8080/result looks like:

```
[
  {"minTime": {"$date": 1459555200000},
    "maxTime": {"$date": 1459555860000},
    "Time": 660.0, "Name": "Sam"},  
  {"minTime": {"$date": 1459558800000},
    "maxTime": {"$date": 1459563265000},
    "Time": 4465.0, "Name": "Bob"},  
  {"minTime": {"$date": 1459562400000},
    "maxTime": {"$date": 1459563842000},
    "Time": 1442.0, "Name": "Sam"},  
    ...  
]
```

I am getting an error

> A negative value is not valid. ("-30.00296 864734321")

and 397 others.

What do these errors mean?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
d.startDate = new Date(d.maxTime.$date);   
d.endDate = new Date(d.minTime.$date);
```

or

```
d.startDate = new Date(d.maxTime["$date"]);   
d.endDate = new Date(d.minTime["$date"]);
```

Comment: I managed to get the time at the bottom but I am getting several other errors now. The guy in example that I've mentioned has hardcoded all the variables. http://static.mentful.com/gantt-chart-d3v2.js

Comment: `var timeDomainStart = d3.time.day.offset(new Date(),-3);var timeDomainEnd = d3.time.hour.offset(new Date(),+3);` in the code you are using, change that to fix your data.